# Extracting Audio from a Game

Tags: pcb, audio

Does anyone know a way which audio can be extracted from PCB boards such as this?

This is what I captured a long time ago from a game from 1998 called Brain Shift, and based on what I asked so far, the chips date back to the 1990's and they come from a company called Sunplus. I have someone at the moment trying to get what I gotten a few years ago but with the static.

This just happened all of a sudden when 'circuit bending' the game with a simple speed control knob changing the pitch of the game.

I know on low batteries this game can do a lot of things like making it count up to 69. Here's the spectogram of the audio that was captured with the static.
[image]